# JQuery: removing char from a String / selecting

Tags: jquery, string, css-selectors

I would like to select only one class from severals with the condition that the selected class has any div-descendant with the id `"#exampleId"`.

I thought something like this could work, but it didn't:

```
$(".myClass").has(div).attr("id","#exampleId").
```

The second problem: I have to get rid first of the hash "#".
because the String (#exampleId) has been generated dynamically...
It looks something like this:

```
var myString = "#exampleId"
```

And the following approach didn't work:

```
myString.replace('#','');
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just pass the ID in the selector for `has()`. No need to remove the `#` either.

```
$(".myClass").has("div#exampleId")
```

Or even do it in one selector:

```
$(".myClass:has(div#exampleId)")
```

Comment: Thanks, that solved it !
But just for being curious:
Would the specific string-replacement work like the method asked above ?

Comment: algro: Yes, that would remove all `#` characters. Just remember to store the result somewhere because `replace` doesn't modify the string itself, it returns the modified string.

Answer (score 1):

You already accepted an answer, but I'll throw this one out there anyway.

If you have more than a few `.myClass` elements on the page, it would probably be more efficient to select the `#exampleId` first, then traverse up to the first `.myClass` using [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

```
$('#exampleId').parents('.myClass:first');
```

Or if the ID was in a variable, do this:

```
var myString = "#exampleId";

$(myString).parents('.myClass:first');
```

These will give you the *first* parent of the `#exampleId` that has `.myClass`.

You could use [`.closest('.myClass')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) if you want as well.